# Django : DoesNotExist Error raised in post_signal handler

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-signals

Trying to delete a `Task` instance with its subtasks, I encounter `DoesNotExist: Task matching query does not exist`.

The following is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 218, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py", line 15, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'supertask'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/crackers/views.py", line 73, in delete
    print(task.delete())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1132, in delete
    return collector.delete()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 512, in delete
    signals.post_delete.send(
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
    return [
           ^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/crackers/signals.py", line 10, in reassess_achievement
    if instance.supertask is not None and instance.supertask.completed == False:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 236, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 199, in get_object
    return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thebjko/dev/TrackCracker/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
crackers.models.Task.DoesNotExist: Task matching query does not exist.
```

So far, I have figured out that the error is related to signal handler, since the same error does not occur when

1. the handler does not handle `post_delete` signal. That is when I remove `post_delete` signal from this handler,
2. `instance.supertask is not None`
3. there does not exist `instance.subtasks`.

These cases are mutually exclusive. If the handler does not handle `post_delete`, it does not matter if `instance.supertask is None` or not. If `instance.supertask is not None`, it does not matter if the instance has subtasks or not. If the instance has subtasks, it does not matter if `instance.supertask is None` or not.

For the above cases, the error is not raised and `delete()` method does its job successfully. The error is only raised when the handler handles `post_delete` signal, and there is no supertask related with the instance if it has subtasks.

The error is raised as it enters if statement.

The following is the handler:

```py
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Task)
def reassess_achievement(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('*'*100)   # executed
    if instance.supertask is not None and instance.supertask.completed == False:
        print('#'*100)    # not executed
        ...

    # No job for other cases.
```

But I still have to execute this code whenever I delete task. Why is this error raised and how can I debug it?

---

UPDATE:

If I print `dir(instance)` inside the handler, it does have `'supertask'`. Why can't I use `instance.supertask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/#post-delete)

> Note that the object will no longer be in the database, so be very careful what you do with this instance.

So I have to use `pre_delete` instead.